# how to mock/stub a function with sinon that is not exported and not part of an object

Tags: typescript, jestjs, mocking, sinon, stub

I am working with a typescript project where I have a file called `fullName.ts` containing the following code:

```
function getFullName(name: string):string {
   const fullName = process.env[name];
   return fullName
}

export const exportedFullName: CustomObj = {
   a: getFullName('string-a'),
   b: getFullName('string-b')
}
```

In another file called `helper.ts` I have an import statement at the top that reads:
`import {exportedFullName} from '../../fullName`

Now I am writing a test file called `main.test.ts` that calls a function called `main` (located in a file called `main.ts`). The `main` function will call the `helper` function in `helper.ts`, and I need a way to mock/stub `exportedFullName` that is imported from the `fullName.ts` file. Is there a way to mock/stub the import directly with sinon, and if that's not possible, is it possible to mock the `getFullName` functions in `fullName.ts` such that I can control what the `exportedFullName` object looks like. From the sinon documentation it largely covers functions that are exported/belong to objects, and that isn't the case for the `getFullName` function. If this isn't possible with sinon I'm open to jest but I'd prefer sinon if possible.

Comment: Export objects are read-only by specs. It depends on your case whether you can mock moduleObj.exportedFullName. In case you can't, it should be mocked on module level. Jest provides module mocking. Sinon doesn't. It's unclear which test runner you use.

Comment: I run my tests using ```yarn jest```

Comment: Use Jest module mocking to mock modules then.